# 'XrmFakedContext' does not cointain a definition for 'ExecutePluginWith'

Tags: dataverse, power-platform, fakexrmeasy

I'm trying to upgrade a unit test project to the latest version of FakeXrmEasy 2.1.2 and I'm getting the error below:

'XrmFakedContext' does not cointain a definition for 'ExecutePluginWith' and no accessible extension method 'ExecutePluginWith' accepting a first argument of type 'XrmFakedContext' could be found

Any ideas what I'm missing?
[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen because some methods were moved into dedicated namespaces and so some extra using statements might be necessary.

Please try adding these usings:

```
using FakeXrmEasy.Abstractions.Plugins;
using FakeXrmEasy.Plugins;
```

Also please check the documentation site with other steps that might be useful. In particular the Quick Guide to migrate in 6 steps is probably an essential resource:

https://dynamicsvalue.github.io/fake-xrm-easy-docs/quickstart/migrating-from-1x/